# How to prepare prolog and epilog assembly to intercept function with parameters?

Tags: winapi, assembly, visual-c++, x86, hook

I am fairly proficient in programming, especially C++, but still new to the concept of API hooking and assembly (learning). Currently I am studying dll proxy which should be fairly easy compared to other methods following an article at the [link here: ethicalhacker.net](https://www.ethicalhacker.net/columns/heffner/intercepted-windows-hacking-via-dll-redirection).

I managed to get the proxy dll to work following this sample code from the article,

```
__declspec ( naked ) void myGetProcessDefaultLayout(void)
{ 
     HINSTANCE handle;
     FARPROC function;
     DWORD retaddr;

     __asm{
               pop retaddr
     }
     handle = LoadLibraryA("user33.dll");
     if(!handle){
               MessageBoxA(NULL,"Failed to load user33.dll!","Error",MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
               ExitProcess(0);
     }

     function = GetProcAddress(handle,"GetProcessDefaultLayout");
     if(!function){
               MessageBoxA(NULL,"Failed to load GetProcessDefaultLayout!","Error",MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
               ExitProcess(0);
     }

     MessageBoxA(NULL,"GetProcessDefaultLayout called!","Hooked!",MB_OK);

     __asm{
               call far dword ptr function
               push retaddr
               retn
     }

}
```

Although the article explained the purpose of the assembly code at the beginning and end of the function, I am still 'blur' on how it actually works as I am still new to assembly. This is still quite a straight forward example, but I want to know how the assembly codes should be designed when the function call has more parameters such as below?

```
funcA(char* srcBuffer, int srcBuffer_size, char* dstBuffer, int* dstBuffer_size, BOOL AllowCallbacks = TRUE);
```

Also, when intercepting this function how do I access its parameters to perform some checking? Sorry if this is a trivial question, maybe I searched and studied the wrong materials.

Comment: By popping the return address, it looks like the function is trying to be totally transparent, i.e. so when the wrapper calls the real function, the args will be on the stack as expected.  But then it uses some locals to save stuff on the stack (e.g. `retaddr`) across a call, defeating the purpose of doing that, because `esp` will be below the caller's args.  Or maybe I'm reading this wrong.  Anyway, it's clearly a 32-bit only hack, Windows uses a different calling convention (with some register args) for x86-64.  (Oh, and MSVC inline-asm only works in 32-bit, too.)

Comment: Can I say this is awful? (I question the author of the article you are using)? The naked attribute remove all the stack frame prologue which means _EBP_ won't even be set properly. This means you are going to be be storing local variables into the stack in places you don't expect. if this code runs without a crash it is only by accident IMHO

Comment: Oh wow, that's even worse.  I assumed it would still reserve stack space for locals if you used any (and address them relative to `[esp]`).  `naked` really lets you create badly broken functions!

Answer (score 3):

task in general enough complex, require some assembler code (so different code for x86/x64). inline *CL* assembler not power enough for this task (and for x64 not supported) - need use *masm[64]*. the prolog end epilog stubs need implement in external asm file. this stubs call already *c++* code.

demo example for hook 2 functions in x86 (with *__stdcall* or *__cdecl* calling convention. for *__fastcall* need also save/restore *ecx,edx* in asm stub)

so first asm code (compile as `ML /c /Cp $(InputName).asm` )

```
.686p

WSTRING macro name, text
    ALIGN 2
    name:
    FORC arg, text
    DW '&arg'
    ENDM
    DW 0
endm

ASTRING macro name, text
    name:
    FORC arg, text
    DB '&arg'
    ENDM
    DB 0
endm

BSS segment
    imp_CreateFileW DD 0 ; cache original function address
    imp_CloseHandle DD 0 ; cache original function address
BSS ends

CONST segment
    WSTRING kernel32, <kernel32> ; dllname, share for multiple api
    ASTRING CreateFileW, <CreateFileW> ; api name
    ASTRING CloseHandle, <CloseHandle> ; api name
CONST ends

_TEXT segment

extern ?CommonStub@@YIPAXPB_WPBDPAPAX2@Z : PROC ; void *__fastcall CommonStub(const wchar_t *,const char *,void **,void **)

?hook_CreateFileW@@YGPAXPB_WKKPAU_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES@@KKPAX@Z proc
    push esp
    push offset imp_CreateFileW
    mov ecx,offset kernel32
    mov edx,offset CreateFileW
    call ?CommonStub@@YIPAXPB_WPBDPAPAX2@Z
    jmp eax
?hook_CreateFileW@@YGPAXPB_WKKPAU_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES@@KKPAX@Z endp

?hook_CloseHandle@@YGHPAX@Z proc
    push esp
    push offset imp_CloseHandle
    mov ecx,offset kernel32
    mov edx,offset CloseHandle
    call ?CommonStub@@YIPAXPB_WPBDPAPAX2@Z
    jmp eax
?hook_CloseHandle@@YGHPAX@Z endp

extern ?OnCall@RET_INFO@@QAIHH@Z : PROC ; int __fastcall RET_INFO::OnCall(int)

?retstub@CODE_STUB@@SAXXZ proc
    pop ecx
    mov edx,eax
    call ?OnCall@RET_INFO@@QAIHH@Z
?retstub@CODE_STUB@@SAXXZ endp

_TEXT ends

END
```

here 2 functions prologs for `CreateFileW` and `CloseHandle` - despite code is different - pattern is common for any hooked api (except *__fastcall*) - we call *c++* common prolog function:

```
PVOID __fastcall CommonStub(PCWSTR DllName, PCSTR FunctionName, void** ppfn, void** Params);
```

it take pointer to dll/api name (if we hook only from single dll we can remove first parameter), pointer to `void*` variable where we save original api address (this is optimization, for call `LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress` only once, and then use ready result on sequential calls) and finally pointer to function call stack (`Params[0]` is return address, `Params[1]` - first parameter, and so on). `CommonStub` must return original api address for asm stub. on first call we got it with `GetProcAddress` and save in `*ppfn` and then simply use saved value.

`?retstub@CODE_STUB@@SAXXZ` is common return stub (epilog). really this is most hard part in function hooking. it need if we want have control *after* original api return. if enough (for task) control only *before* api call - code became much more small and simply. so for hook control *after* api return - we obliviously need replace return address in stack, for got this control. but how return to original caller after this ? need save original return address. but where ? we can not use stack for this (not have any stack space), can not use non-volatile register (if use it - need save and restore before return to original caller - but again where save it ?). only solution here - allocate block of *executable* memory - in this block save original return address (mandatory), functional parameters and name (optional) - for know on return which api call ended, and in this block must be some tiny base-independ code-stub - this stub call our asm epilog - `?retstub@CODE_STUB@@SAXXZ` with *pointer* to this executable memory block. by using this pointer we restore original return address, inspect api return value and return to original caller. note also - here i assume that api return value in single *eax* register (*rax* for x64) this is true for 99%+ api. however exist some api which return 2 registers *edx:eax* pair. this case of course can be handled, but for for simplicity i not show it here (code anyway too big)

you can ask, how i format/know this complex *c++* names in asm ? i got it with help this macros in *c++* code:

```
#if 1 //0
#define __ASM_FUNCTION __pragma(message(__FUNCDNAME__" proc\r\n" __FUNCDNAME__ " endp"))
#define _ASM_FUNCTION {__ASM_FUNCTION;}
#define ASM_FUNCTION {__ASM_FUNCTION;return 0;}
#define CPP_FUNCTION __pragma(message("extern " __FUNCDNAME__ " : PROC ; "  __FUNCSIG__))
#else
#define _ASM_FUNCTION
#define ASM_FUNCTION
#define CPP_FUNCTION
#endif
```

`#if 1` need use at compile time for get c++ decorated names (paste it to asm). and before final compile build replace to `#if 0`.

now looking for *c++* code. the 90%+ of code take implement and manage executable memory buffers - need for support control after api return.

```
SLIST_HEADER g_head;
PVOID g_BaseAddress, g_pExport;

class CODE_STUB
{
#ifdef _WIN64
    PVOID pad;
#endif
    union
    {
        DWORD code;
        struct  
        {
            BYTE cc[3];
            BYTE call;
        };
    };
    int offset;

public:

    void Init(PVOID stub)
    {   
        code = 0xe8cccccc;// int3; int3; int3; call retstub
        offset = RtlPointerToOffset(&offset + 1, stub);
    }

    PVOID Function()
    {
        return &call;
    }

    // implemented in .asm
    static void __cdecl retstub()  _ASM_FUNCTION;
};

struct RET_INFO 
{
    union
    {
        SLIST_ENTRY Entry;

        struct  
        {
            PCSTR Name;
            PVOID params[7];
        };
    };

    INT_PTR __fastcall OnCall(INT_PTR r);
};

struct RET_FUNC : CODE_STUB, RET_INFO 
{
};

#pragma bss_seg(".HOOKS")
RET_FUNC g_rf[1024];//max concurent call count
#pragma bss_seg() 

#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.HOOKS,RWE")

class RET_FUNC_Manager 
{
    SLIST_HEADER _head;

public:

    RET_FUNC_Manager()
    {
        PSLIST_HEADER head = &_head;

        InitializeSListHead(head);

        RET_FUNC* p = g_rf;
        DWORD n = RTL_NUMBER_OF(g_rf);

        do 
        {
            p->Init(CODE_STUB::retstub);
            InterlockedPushEntrySList(head, &p++->Entry);
        } while (--n);
    }

    RET_FUNC* alloc()
    {
        return static_cast<RET_FUNC*>(CONTAINING_RECORD(InterlockedPopEntrySList(&_head), RET_INFO, Entry));
    }

    void free(RET_INFO* p)
    {
        InterlockedPushEntrySList(&_head, &p->Entry);
    }
} g_rfm;

INT_PTR __fastcall RET_INFO::OnCall(INT_PTR r)
{
    CPP_FUNCTION;

    *(void**)_AddressOfReturnAddress() = *params;

    g_rfm.free(this);
    return r;
}

PVOID __fastcall CommonStub(PCWSTR DllName, PCSTR FunctionName, void** ppfn, void** Params)
{
    CPP_FUNCTION;

    //++ optional, hook return
    if (RET_FUNC* p = g_rfm.alloc())
    {
        p->Name = FunctionName;
        // memcpy(p->params, Params, sizeof(p->params)); // save original return address and params
        PVOID StackBase = reinterpret_cast<PNT_TIB>(NtCurrentTeb())->StackBase;
        PVOID ParamsBase = Params + RTL_NUMBER_OF(p->params);
        ParamsBase = min(StackBase, ParamsBase);
        memcpy(p->params, Params, RtlPointerToOffset(Params, ParamsBase));

        *Params = p->Function();// replace return address
    }
    //-- optional

    PVOID pfn = *ppfn;

    if (!pfn)
    {
        if (pfn = GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryW(DllName), FunctionName))
        {
            *ppfn = pfn;
        }
        else
        {
            __debugbreak();
        }
    }

    return pfn;
}
```

i name it `RET_FUNC` (structure for this buffers) and pre-allocate in *PE* body :

```
#pragma bss_seg(".HOOKS")
RET_FUNC g_rf[1024];//max concurent call count
#pragma bss_seg() 

#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.HOOKS,RWE")
```

this is mandatory for x64 support (i use relative call in memory block to asm stub - so both codes must be in range -/+2GB - when both inside *PE* this will be automatically true)

1024 - is count of how many api calls we support in concurrent. in practice this value more than enough. however even if we fail allocate memory block for some api call - we simply not control return from this api, but not fail call api and just return to original caller. the array of `g_rf[1024];` i push to lock-free stack structure by using `SLIST_HEADER`, `InterlockedPopEntrySList` (for allocate entry) and `InterlockedPushEntrySList` (for free entry). this is maximal fast, and effective.

*c++* common prolog is `CommonStub` - here we can inspect functions parameter before call and optional hook return (`*Params = p->Function();`).

*c++* common epilog is `INT_PTR __fastcall RET_INFO::OnCall(INT_PTR r)` - here `r` is register size api return value (from *eax* or *rax*). in class `RET_INFO` exist all needed information about api call. here we can ispect return value, api name, save call-stack. however in this demo code i implement only mandatory task: restore return address `*(void**)_AddressOfReturnAddress() = *params;` (by this trick we return direct to original api caller after return, not to our asm stub epilog)

[`_AddressOfReturnAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/addressofreturnaddress) is *CL* Intrinsic (so not support by another compilers, but i guess they have some equivalent). and finally we free (push to stack) allocated executable memory block - `g_rfm.free(this);`. function return `r` - the api call result (again note i guess api used single register). after return from `INT_PTR __fastcall RET_INFO::OnCall(INT_PTR r)` - we just will be in original caller code with correct stack and api return value in *eax* (*rax*). however, if need we can return not `r` but another value - so change api call result.

code for x64 asm even more simply, because exist common calling convention.

`ml64 /c /Cp /Zd $(InputFileName) -> $(InputName).obj`

```
WSTRING macro name, text
    ALIGN 2
    name:
    FORC arg, text
    DW '&arg'
    ENDM
    DW 0
endm

ASTRING macro name, text
    name:
    FORC arg, text
    DB '&arg'
    ENDM
    DB 0
endm

BSS segment
    imp_CreateFileW DQ 0 ; cache original function address
    imp_CloseHandle DQ 0 ; cache original function address
BSS ends

CONST segment
    WSTRING kernel32, <kernel32> ; dllname, share for multiple api
    ASTRING CreateFileW, <CreateFileW> ; api name
    ASTRING CloseHandle, <CloseHandle> ; api name
CONST ends

_TEXT segment

extern ?OnCall@RET_INFO@@QEAA_J_J@Z : PROC ; __int64 __cdecl RET_INFO::OnCall(__int64)

?retstub@CODE_STUB@@SAXXZ proc
  pop rcx
  mov rdx,rax
  call ?OnCall@RET_INFO@@QEAA_J_J@Z
?retstub@CODE_STUB@@SAXXZ endp

extern ?CommonStub@@YAPEAXPEB_WPEBDPEAPEAX2@Z : PROC ; void *__cdecl CommonStub(const wchar_t *,const char *,void **,void **)

?hook_CreateFileW@@YAPEAXPEB_WKKPEAU_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES@@KKPEAX@Z proc
    mov [rsp+32],r9
    mov [rsp+24],r8
    mov [rsp+16],rdx
    mov [rsp+8],rcx
    mov r9,rsp
    lea r8,imp_CreateFileW
    lea rdx,CreateFileW
    lea rcx,kernel32
    sub rsp,40
    call ?CommonStub@@YAPEAXPEB_WPEBDPEAPEAX2@Z
    add rsp,40
    mov rcx,[rsp+8]
    mov rdx,[rsp+16]
    mov r8,[rsp+24]
    mov r9,[rsp+32]
    jmp rax
?hook_CreateFileW@@YAPEAXPEB_WKKPEAU_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES@@KKPEAX@Z endp

?hook_CloseHandle@@YAHPEAX@Z proc
    mov [rsp+32],r9
    mov [rsp+24],r8
    mov [rsp+16],rdx
    mov [rsp+8],rcx
    mov r9,rsp
    lea r8,imp_CloseHandle
    lea rdx,CloseHandle
    lea rcx,kernel32
    sub rsp,40
    call ?CommonStub@@YAPEAXPEB_WPEBDPEAPEAX2@Z
    add rsp,40
    mov rcx,[rsp+8]
    mov rdx,[rsp+16]
    mov r8,[rsp+24]
    mov r9,[rsp+32]
    jmp rax
?hook_CloseHandle@@YAHPEAX@Z endp

_TEXT ends

end
```

---

about `RET_INFO` - `PVOID params[7];` - this allow save (for use after api call up to 6 parameters (in params[0] will be return address)). however we can redefine to say `PVOID params[15];` - will be used up to 14 parameters.

however simply copy fixed count of parameters from stack

```
memcpy(p->params, Params, sizeof(p->params));
```

not [quite] correct, because we can out from stack range (if say call direct from thread entry point and function, which do call almost not use local variables - so stack very near top). to be correct need check stack base, before copy:

```
    PVOID StackBase = reinterpret_cast<PNT_TIB>(NtCurrentTeb())->StackBase;
    PVOID ParamsBase = Params + RTL_NUMBER_OF(p->params);
    ParamsBase = min(StackBase, ParamsBase);
    memcpy(p->params, Params, RtlPointerToOffset(Params, ParamsBase));
```

or instead memcpy can even do next optimization:

```
#if defined(_M_IX86) 
#define __movsp __movsd
#elif defined (_M_X64)
#define __movsp __movsq
#else
#error
#endif
    __movsp((PULONG_PTR)p->params, 
        (PULONG_PTR)Params, 
        RtlPointerToOffset(Params, ParamsBase)/ sizeof(ULONG_PTR));
```

also note about x64:
you can see:

```
class CODE_STUB
{
#ifdef _WIN64
    PVOID pad;// for what ?
#endif
```

because in win64 `SLIST_ENTRY` must be 16 byte aligned. it declared in *winnt.h* with `DECLSPEC_ALIGN(16)`. as result `RET_INFO` (containing `SLIST_ENTRY`) and inherited from it `struct RET_FUNC : CODE_STUB, RET_INFO {}` will be 16 byte aligned. must be:

```
C_ASSERT(__alignof(RET_FUNC)==16);
```

this will be anyway - with and without `PVOID pad;` in begin of `CODE_STUB`. but my code implicit use (need) that

```
C_ASSERT(sizeof(CODE_STUB) == RTL_SIZEOF_THROUGH_FIELD(CODE_STUB, offset));
C_ASSERT(FIELD_OFFSET(RET_FUNC, Entry)==sizeof(CODE_STUB));// !!
```

or in other words between `CODE_STUB` (end of `offset` member) and begin of `RET_INFO` no pad - in `CODE_STUB` - `call offset` instruction and return address, pushed in stack is .. pointer to `RET_INFO` must be - i pop return address from stack and use as pointer to `RET_INFO` for call member function `RET_INFO::OnCall`:

```
?retstub@CODE_STUB@@SAXXZ proc
  pop rcx ; -> RET_INFO
  mov rdx,rax
  call ?OnCall@RET_INFO@@QEAA_J_J@Z
?retstub@CODE_STUB@@SAXXZ endp
```

without `PVOID pad` - `CODE_STUB` is 8 byte ( 3*1 byte (int 3) + 5 byte relative *call offset*) but `RET_INFO` (due 16 byte `SLIST_ENTRY Entry;` it member align) will begin at 16 offset from `RET_FUNC`. so compiler anyway implicit insert 8 byte pad, but at the end of `CODE_STUB` between `CODE_STUB` and `RET_INFO`:

`RET_FUNC : CODE_STUB, /* 8 byte pad/ RET_INFO` will be. for avoid this - need explicitly add this 8 byte pad, but to begin of `CODE_STUB`. with this all will be correct. note that for replace original return address we use

```
*Params = p->Function()
```

where

```
PVOID Function()
{
    return &call;
}
```

return address of *call offset* instruction in `CODE_STUB` (instead address of `CODE_STUB`) - so this correct handle any pad at begin - we anyway got correct address or return stub

Comment: Very nice. There is a parameter limit in RET_INFO though so people need to be aware of that.

Comment: @Anders - yes, added clarification on this point (we really can increase array element cout). however initial, simply copy parameters from stack not correct (we can run out of top stack limit)- add code which check this and copy less parameters in this case. + asm code x64 and clarification for special align (pad at begin of CODE_STUB) on x64

Answer (score 2):

That guide is horrible.

> ... we will copy the original user32.dll file into the Internet Explorer directory

This instantly makes it unusable on other systems. Even if you make the copy on the target system it will not help much because the functions exported by user32 changes over time and your man in the middle .DLL will probably not contain the correct exports/forwarders.

The code example does not make a lot of sense either. You cannot really combine `__declspec(naked)` with local C variables. MSVC might even expect there to be a stack frame and use EBP to access those local variables. The function as it is written could just be coded in C without any inline assembly.

The purpose of the inline assembly is probably to handle cases where the function has parameters.

If we imagine you are hooking SetLastError instead. When the hook (mySetLastError) is called the stack would look like this on 32-bit x86:

```
- Return address (Top of stack, pushed by the parent functions `call`)
- Param 1
- Unknown (probably parent functions local variables etc)
```

If you then remove the return address you would be left with the parameters and this would be perfect for making a `call` to the real function inside the hook. The problem is that this does not actually work in practice. You cannot easily `pop` the return address because you have nowhere to store it. The only way I can think of that could make this work would be to use TLS to store a pointer to your own stack of return addresses for the thread.

That might look something like this:

```
FARPROC GetRealSetLastError()
{
  static FARPROC cache = 0;
  if (!cache) cache = GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA("kernel32"), "SetLastError");
  return cache;
}

void WINAPI SaveReturn(void*RetAddr)
{
  // TODO: Append to an array stored in TLS
}

void* RestoreReturnHelper()
{
  // TODO: Remove from array and return it
}
__declspec(naked) void* RestoreReturn()
{ __asm {
   push eax ; Save real return value (must also protect edx if you are hooking something that returns a int64)
   call RestoreReturnHelper
   pop ecx
   push eax ; Return address
   mov eax, ecx ; Restore real return value
   ret
} }

__declspec(naked) void WINAPI mySetLastError(UINT error)
{ __asm {

  call SaveReturn ; Removes the return address from the stack
  call GetRealSetLastError ; Could be replaced by push, call, push, push, call to LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress but you probably want to cache the function pointer if speed is important
  call eax ; Call the real function
  call RestoreReturn ; Restore the original return address (without messing up eax)
  ret 
} }
```

This trick would not work if you target anything other than 32-bit x86. If the target was AMD64 then `SaveReturn` would also have to be coded in assembly because the first parameters are not stored on the stack so the "pop as a function call" trick will not work.

It really depends on which application you are hooking but if you can modify the application **or** use a launcher that injects a thread then you can just use [IAT hooking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking#Internal_IAT_Hooking) or [Detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/) instead and save yourself the pain of maintaining a copy of a Microsoft .DLL.

Comment: HAHA I posted a comment about that under the question around the same time.. You called it horrible, I called it awful. I think I like your adjective better

Comment: really this is almost impossible implement with c/c++ only (naked functions/inline assembler). need masm or another asm use for write subs. and main note -  use TLS or here not need. exist more clean solution

Comment: @RbMm You could at least just describe your solution right here.